# phpmyadmin forbidden after changing config for my IP

Tags: apache-2.4, server-setup

I followed the phpmyadmin setup and changed the config to `require ip my ipaddress` and `allow from my ipaddress` and its still telling me `forbidden You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.` when I try to access the page on my browser (my server is not located on my machine). I installed everything using `root`. I also chmod 775 the entire phpMyAdmin folder. Im running RHEL 6.1. Any idea what to do at this point?

Here is my `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf`:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
      # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
      Require ip myserveripaddress
      Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from myserveripaddress
     Allow from ::1
    </IfModule>
 </Directory>
```

Comment: You need to give much more details, not just throwing in some unrelated message fragments. E.g. do you get the "forbidden" message from Apache or phpmysql? What has the change of the file permissions do to with that? Details, and precise configurations.

Comment: updated the question. sorry about that.

Comment: Are you running the browser on the same machine as phpmyadmin ?

Comment: no. i updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Allow from myserverip` lines are preventing you from accessing the service. This way, Apache allows only requests orginating from this IP, but since you are using it from the IP of your client system, the requests will fail.

Comment: Im going to http://myserveripaddress/phpmyadmin

Comment: Yes, but the request comes from your client IP address and that is what these config lines are about.

Comment: That worked! I understand now.